# Click a link in Safari that is inside a table

Tags: javascript, applescript

Essentially I have a link inside of a huge table in safari. I want to always click row 2 column 1. The name of the link changes that is inside that cell.

Here is the HTML
http://pastebin.com/UuwFfcyG

I put a visual marker in the code where I want to click. But in this example you could search for "1222" and it will pull right up.

Basically once that link is clicked it opens a window which i can hack around and use system events to tab and select stuff and then reload the page and do it again.

Bonus if you can tell me how to check the text in the next column. Row 2 Column 2. If it says "open" then click on the link in the cell to the left.

Full disclosure I have written a AppleScript program that does this, but it does it using python clicks governed by screen coordinates, so if the resolution changes or I add another monitor it breaks the program. It's so hacky but it definitely works. I am just looking for something more native.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks
Brandon

Answer (score 0):

So you automatically want to see if there is a link in row 2, column 1 of this table and click on it?

```
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
function clickLinksInTable(i) {
    // check if a link even exists in this row
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i+1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0] || !document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i+1].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]) {
        // fail silently.
    } else {
        // check if the next column to the right contains the word "open" .
        if (document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i+1].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf("open") != -1) {
            // get the row (tr) that the user wants (the first row never contains a link, so add one to i to avoid this being a problem)
            // then get the first column (td) in that row, and then get the first (probably only) link in that column.
            link = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i+1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            // then... click on it! While we're mainly focussed on Safari, it's good to support other browsers as well,
            // just in case we want to use this code again elsewhere.
            // Firefox
            if (document.createEvent) {
                var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                event.initEvent("click", true, true);
                link.dispatchEvent(event);
            }
            // IE
            else if (link.click) {
                link.click();
            }
        }
    }
}
// call the function we made earlier. The value in brackets is the row number of the link you want to click.
// this will click the link in row two, column one.
clickLinksInTable(0);
// this would click the link in row five, column one.
//clickLinksInTable(3);
</script>
```

Add this after your table.

Comment: There is always a link there. But I don't need to click it it unless it says open

Comment: does this do what you want now?
Or did you mean Row 2, Column 3? The one which says Expired here? Currently I have it checking Row 2, Column 2.

Comment: Forgive me I am not sure how I can wrap this in Applescript. Is it possible just to click on that link with one line? I can add logic through Applescript if I can figure out how to click that first link. 
I am not really that worried about reading the other line, but if there is just one line that i can use to maybe copy it to the clipboard or even better store that string in a variable I can maybe figure out how to pass it back to applescript. Also I really appreciate your help.
http://i.imgur.com/iMPQdjK.png

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I was under the impression that this was a JavaScript question, in which case you could take the code above and add it after your table in the HTML document.

Comment: That is probably my fault. I tagged it under both and I'm new to stack overflow so I apologize.

Comment: Yeah normally this would go after </table> in the sample you uploaded and you'd call clickLinksInTable for whatever link it is you want to click

Comment: the AppleScript dictionary of Safari has a `do JavaScript` command